# Rails migration blocked by "foreign key constraint failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run a relatively simple rails migration to remove a column:

```
class Removetopicsfromquestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :questions do |t|
      t.remove :topic_id
    end
  end
end
```

It fails due to "foreign key constraint":

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed: DROP TABLE "questions"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
etc...
```

And for reference this is what the table currently looks like:

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "topic_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "explanation"
    t.boolean "published", default: true
    t.string "usage", default: "Free Quiz", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "variant", default: "fill", null: false
    t.string "correct"
    t.string "alt_one"
    t.string "alt_two"
    t.string "alt_three"
    t.string "editor"
    t.boolean "accepted"
    t.string "reference"
    t.text "context"
    t.string "questionable_type"
    t.integer "questionable_id"
    t.index ["questionable_type", "questionable_id"], name: "index_questions_on_questionable_type_and_questionable_id"
  end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is :topic, :topics, or :topic_id referenced as an association in any of your models?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something like this at the bottom of your schema?

```
add_foreign_key "questions", "topics"
```

Rails cannot remove this column from the table because there is a foreign key added.  Try this instead inside your migration file:

```
def change
  remove_reference :questions, :topic, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I do not appear to have any foreign keys in my entire schema.rb file.